# Submit Button Image

Tags: html, css, submit

I want to use a Submit Button Image instead of the standard Button. I searched on Google and SO and got a few different ways.

Which is the right way of using an Image as a Submit Button ?

Also i would want to add three states for the button - normal, hover, onclick

What i tried

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
```

CSS

```
input[type=submit] {
    background:url(../images/btn-subscribe.gif) none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    width:109px;
    height:41px;
}
```

What shows up

[image]

What it should Display

[image]

Comment: Either remove `text-indent` and add `value="Subscribe"` in `<input>` or add the letters `Subscribe` on the image

Comment: @Harsha M V: See my answer below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Edited:**

I think you are trying to do as done in this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9UZF/)

**There are three states of a button: normal, hover and active**

You need to use [**CSS Image Sprites**](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for the button states.

[**See The Mystery of CSS Sprites**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/)

```css
/*CSS*/

.imgClass { 
background-image: url(http://inspectelement.com/wp-content/themes/inspectelementv2/style/images/button.png);
background-position:  0px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 186px;
height: 53px;
border: 0px;
background-color: none;
cursor: pointer;
outline: 0;
}
.imgClass:hover{ 
  background-position:  0px -52px;
}

.imgClass:active{
  background-position:  0px -104px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="submit" value="" class="imgClass" />
```

Comment: For user-interface optimization I always add the css-rule `cursor: pointer;`. It changes the cursor to the hand icon on hover, just like links do by default.

Comment: WARNING, some browsers (Chrome) force some styles on submit. This issue appears when you use transparent PNG as submit background - overall background will have color = "buttonface" and will not be 100% transparent. Add background-color: transparent.

Comment: The link to the image you used is broken.

Answer (score 11):

```
<input type="image" src="path to image" name="submit" />
```

UPDATE:

For button states, you can use type="submit" and then add a class to it

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="states" />
```

Then in css, use background images for:

```
.states{
background-image:url(path to url);
height:...;
width:...;
}

.states:hover{
background-position:...;
}

.states:active{
background-position:...;
}
```

Comment: is adding the name=submit the key ?

Comment: What if i want to add button states ?

Comment: @HarshaMV What lbu said. `name` can be used to check for button click. For ex: In php `if(isset($_POST['name']))`

Comment: have updated my question. thats what i am getting when i try to add a bg image

Comment: @HarshaMV Made a comment below your question

Answer (score 9):

`<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="images/submit.gif" HEIGHT="30" WIDTH="173" BORDER="0" ALT="Submit Form">`
Where the standard submit button has `TYPE="submit"`, we now have `TYPE="image"`. The image type is by default a form submitting button. More simple

Answer (score 4):

It's very important for accessibility reasons that you always specify value of the submit even if you are hiding this text, or if you use `<input type="image" .../>` to always specify `alt=""` attribute for this input field.

Blind people don't know what button will do if it doesn't contain meaningful `alt=""` or `value=""`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the borders and add a background image on the input.

```
.imgClass { 
    background-image: url(path to image) no-repeat;
    width: 186px;
    height: 53px;
    border: none;
}
```

It should be good now, normally.