# Changing submit image of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to get submit image to change to no avail

```
<input type="image" name="submit" value="Login" src="../media/Login.png" 

onclick="this.src='../media/Loginned.png';" style="cursor:default;" />
```

This is not working, really not sure why. Would be nice to get a little help.

Comment: Random: Is it really called `Loginned`?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sAX2B/

Comment: Why do you need to change the image? Are you submitting the form?

Comment: provide your whole code or try changing src path of img

Comment: Yeah it's called Loginned. Lol, submitted version of all the buttons just has ned at the end. lmao

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit Button Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772326/submit-button-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should be working -- provided you're not actually submitting, and causing the page to refresh. Have you tried adding `;return false` to your click event?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
onclick="this.src='../media/Loginned.png'; return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
      <input type="image" name="submit" value="Login" src="media/Login.png" 
       onclick="this.src='media/Loginned.png';" style="cursor:default;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give absolute path to image

```
../imagepath
```

will not work.